# SessionStateModule vs runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, iis-7.5, httpmodule, integrated-pipeline-mode

At the moment I have the attribute `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` set, so my modules are running for all the requests. I guess that includes the `SessionStateModule`.

When trying to access the session object in the `PostAcquireRequestState` event handler in one of my custom modules, the `HttpContext.Current.Session` is null when the `HttpApplication.Context.CurrentHandler` is null (e.g.: for a JS/CSS file), and it is not null when the handler is `MvcHandler` (because it is a managed handler I guess).

I have been taking a look to the `SessionStateModule` code in ILSpy and I couldn't find where is taking the decision of skip Session for that request.

I have been looking in `%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config` and there is no mention of `SessionStateModule`, and in the `Web.config` in that folder I found:

```
<add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule" />
```

So it is not using any precondition like `managedHandler`.

Does anybody know why is the `SessionStateModule` skipping requests for non-managed resources even when the attribute `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests` is set?

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems IIS loads default modules with the managed handler precondition to ensure backward compatibility.
http://forums.iis.net/post/1904024.aspx

Comment: As per this link: http://www.iis.net/learn/get-started/introduction-to-iis/iis-modules-overview#Precondition when you have runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests=true, preCondition has no effect. This behaviour though may differ based on the pipeline mode (integrated OR classic). You could probably add what pipeline mode you're using.